# health kit observer query always called when the app becomes active

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, healthkit

The `resultHandler` of `HKObserverQuery` is always called when the app becomes active (background -> foreground)

But, I wrote the code of the query in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate.swift`. I know the method is called when the app is launched not the app become active.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    healthStore.authorizeHealthKit {
        ...
    }
}
// other AppDelegate methods are empty
```

How do I make the handler of the query called only when my app is launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to prevent the updateHandler from firing?

You can't control when the updateHandler of an `HKObserverQuery` fires while the query is running.  You can prevent it from being called at all by stopping the query.  It is designed to be called whenever there might be new HealthKit data matching your predicate.  You should design your `updateHandler` such that it doesn't matter when it is called.

If you really wanted the observer query to not fire when your app returns to the foreground, you would need to stop the query completely with `-[HKHealthStore stopQuery:]` when your app enters the background, before it suspends.

Comment: I want firing of the `updateHandler` only when some health kit samples are added. Returning to the foreground doesn't mean that some new samples are added.

Comment: The worst that is going to happen is that your app will re-query and find nothing new.  HKObserverQuery does not provide guarantees about how many times updateHandler is called, it is an advisory signal that data you are interested may have been added or deleted.

Comment: Hi @Allan, the problem is that it slows down app work. Lets consider situation when you have local cache of HK data (i.e. steps) for quick access and you want to keep it synced with HK. You set up observer queries and re-sync data when one of them is fired. This means that every time the app becomes active you have to re-request all data again (as all observer queries are fired) which takes quite a lot of time. Also in this case there is no point in using observer queries at all as you can just reload all data every time your app becomes active.

Comment: @Allan It would be really helpful if Apple could improve observer mechanism in such a way that observer queries would be fired only when there is new data ;) Thanks!

Comment: You should use HKAnchoredObjectQuery with an update handler if you want to keep your app in sync with HealthKit. It is designed for precisely the case that you describe.

Comment: @Allan I missed this option, my fault. Thank you!